# ARIAC conveyor belt in other projects?

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello.

I am trying to get the conveyor belt plugin from Ariac competition to work on my own project, where I need to simulate a conveyor belt moving items.

Is it possible? I have cloned the ariac data from [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/ariac/src/master/), added my own package in the source.

**Edit**

I created a simple test conveyor, but I don't see any topics popping up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<robot name="conveyor_system">
  <link name="frame_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1" iyz="0.0" izz="1"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.505 0.0 0.05"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="1.01 0.21 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="silver">
        <color rgba="0.7 0.7 0.7 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.505 0.0 0.05"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="1.01 0.21 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="belt_joint" type="prismatic">
    <parent link="frame_link"/>
    <child link="belt_link"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-0.5" upper="0.5" velocity="0.5"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="belt_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1" iyz="0.0" izz="1"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.505 0.0 0.205"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="1 0.2 0.01"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="green">
        <color rgba="0 1 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.505 0.0 0.05"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="1.01 0.21 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <gazebo reference="belt_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Green</material>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo>
    <static>true</static>
    <plugin filename="libRosConveyorBeltPlugin.so" name="conveyor_belt_plugin">
      <robot_namespace>/tbelt</robot_namespace>
      <enable_topic>/tbelt/enable</enable_topic>
      <population_rate_modifier_topic>/tbelt/population/rate_modifier</population_rate_modifier_topic>
      <link>belt_link</link>
      <power>0</power>
      <update_rate>10</update_rate>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
```

I would appreciate any help, I will also submit more information if needed, since I don't know what to post.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25918/ariac-conveyor-belt-in-other-projects?/) by [gurnarok](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34097/gurnarok/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-10-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yah130s](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1228/yah130s/) on 2020-10-12**:
I'm also very interested in utilizing conveyor belt from ARIAC pkgs. That said, you might get better responses by asking concrete questions (otherwise I'm afraid you wouldn't get answers).

**Comment by [gurnarok](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34097/gurnarok/) on 2020-10-12**:
Made a edit, giving a concrete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I made a new github repository for the ARIAC conveyor belt. You can find it here: https://github.com/rokokoo/gazebo-conveyor

I am working on making a example package, that shows it working.

---

Originally posted by [gurnarok](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34097/gurnarok/) with karma: 11 on 2020-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You need to fix the plugin filename libROSConveyorBeltPlugin.so, the joint limits [0, 1], and the joint axis (1, 0, 0).

These will get the plugin running, but you still need to fix the geometries in your model.

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-10-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gurnarok](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34097/gurnarok/) on 2020-10-13**:
Thank you, I didn't notice my typo on the plugin.

I got it to load,but when I run rostopic list, I only get the following topics:

```
$ rostopic list
/clock
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/joint_states
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tbelt/conveyor/state
/tf
/tf_static
```

There is no enable topic, so I can't "power on" the belt.

**Comment by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) on 2020-10-13**:
The enable topic is a gazebo topic. You might wanna fork the plugin and expose a better interface. The implementation is straightforward, should be fairly simple to do it.

**Comment by [gurnarok](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34097/gurnarok/) on 2020-10-13**:
I got it to work, using the service call for it. I just need to reconfigure the geometry of the model and try to get it to work a little bit better. Now it jumps to the side when it tries to reset the position.

**Comment by [erikkkk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/37996/erikkkk/) on 2020-12-11**:
hello, i used your code and corrected it as this answer said. but when i call the service of conveyor control, it always fails
"Belt is not currently enabled so power cannot be set. It may be congested."
i don't understand whats wrong and as i am not familiar with C++, i cannot fix this problem from reading source code neither...
If you had any ideal, could you please help me with this error?

**Comment by [erikkkk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/37996/erikkkk/) on 2020-12-11**:
oh i find your plugin above there and it works. thanks very much!